# Android ProgressDialog not dismissing from Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable, progressdialog

i'm developing an android App.
The user registration process calls a service that sends an email so it takes several seconds, like 5 or 6 seconds,that's why I execute that task within a thread. The problem is, the Dialog is never dismissing. It stays rolling and the user can do nothing. Here's my code:

```
try
        {
        final ProgressDialog progDailog = new ProgressDialog(ActividadAltaUsuario.this);

        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                URL url = new URL("slowWS");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                String response = IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
                final JSONObject jsonPrincipal = new JSONObject(response);
                Boolean success = jsonPrincipal.get("status").toString() == "true";

                if (success)
                {
                    ActividadAltaUsuario.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progDailog.show(ActividadAltaUsuario.this, "Sendind email");
                        }
                    });

                    final String idUsuario = jsonPrincipal.get("idUsuario").toString();
                    URL url2 = new URL("anotherSlowWS");
                    HttpURLConnection conn2 = (HttpURLConnection) url2.openConnection();
                    conn2.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    InputStream in2 = new BufferedInputStream(conn2.getInputStream());
                    String response2 = IOUtils.toString(in2, "UTF-8");
                    JSONObject jsonRtaMail = new JSONObject(response2);
                    //finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    //finish();
                    showToast(jsonPrincipal.get("message").toString());
                }

                ActividadAltaUsuario.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        progDailog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
        }).start();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());
        }
```

Can anybody help me?
Thanks!

Comment: did you debug and checked that your method run onuithread is being called and getting inside the method

Comment: @AbdulWaheed yes, it's getting inside the mehtod! i checked it!

Comment: did you try to run the dismiss function on the UI thread with runOnUiThread(new Runnable(...)); ?

Comment: @GabriellaAngelova That's the way I'm doing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncTask would be a better approach instead of thread, Replace your network call from thread to use AsyncTask. You can use something like this

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Main stuff that needs to be done in background

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //Post Execution this method will be called, handle result accordingly
        //You can dismiss your dialog here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Do initialization relative stuff here
        // Initialize your dialog here.
    }
}
```

As both `onPostExecute()` and `onPreExecute()` work on main thread you can show and dismiss your dialog in this methods.

Comment: That's a good idea, but the post Execute part, depends on the result of WS call. How can i get that result ? can those methods communicate with each other?

Comment: these params `<Void, Void, Void>` are for a reason, you can use them to pass different values based on your requirement. check this demo https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Comment: I implemmented AsyncTask and all worked perfect, but still dismiss is not working! Where should i declare the ProgressDialog?

Comment: I replaced:
progDailog.show(ActividadAltaUsuario.this, "Sendind email");
with:
progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(ActividadAltaUsuario.this, "Sendind email");
And all worked perfect. That was the problem. But thanks anyway. Now my code is much more correct and neat

Answer (score 0):

The UI controls have to be accessed only from the UI thread.
Usually I do this in class that extends AsyncTask

Something like:
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    protected void onPreExecute() {
//create and display your alert here 
    progDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this,"Please wait...", "Logging ...", true);
}

protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

    // here is the thread's work ( what is on your method run()
    ...
    // if we want to show some progress in UI, then call 
    publishProgress(item)
}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Item... item) {
    // theoretically you can show the progress here
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
    //dismiss dialog here where the thread has finished his work
    progDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

**LE:**
More detalis about AsyncTask https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask
check especially the Protected Methods